# Why does double empty curly braces { { } } create a std::initializer_list<double> with one element, not zero?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have the following constructor:

```
MyItem(std::initializer_list<double> l) {
    std::cout << "l size " << l.size() << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Which is called later with double curly braces:

```
MyItem{{}}
```

The result l.size() gives is 1.

What's the mechanics behind such behavior?

It seems like nested {} plays like a default constructor for the only element, but I don't quite understand why and how type deduction works here.

Comment: Take into account that there is a Russian stackoverflow at http://ru.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use braces (list-initialization) to initialize the `MyItem` object, the list constructor you have shown is very greedy.

These would pass an empty list:

```
MyItem foo({});
MyItem foo{std::initializer_list<double>{}};
```

This passes a list containing a single element - a value-initialized `double` (0.0):

```
MyItem foo{{}};
```

This works because there are certain contexts where you can simply use braces in place of a known type. Here, it knows from preferring the list constructor that the given list should contain `double`.

For completeness, this looks like it passes an empty list, but it actually value-initializes `foo` if it has a default constructor (or in special cases, does something almost equivalent). If there's no default constructor, it would choose the list constructor, [as shown here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c206fef140e35d8).

```
MyItem foo{};
```

Comment: Could you how exactly it deduces the type? Does { } play role of default constructor? There is no type or `auto` specified. I'm interested in mechanics like what steps compiler takes to deduce it.

Comment: @NikolayPolivanov, This might be the most tricky context where braces are allowed like this. In general, they're allowed when you would be repeating the type and the compiler already knows it. For example, you have `void foo(string)`. Let's say you want to pass the first n characters of "abcde", where n is a variable. You'd normally do something like `foo(string("abcde", n));`. However, it's obviously a string, so why repeat the type? `foo({"abcde", n});` When you use `{}`, it's typically value-initialization, which is usually 0 or the default constructor. `foo({});` passes an empty string.

Comment: Even then, the list constructor is very greedy. For example, `std::string` has a list constructor taking a list of `char`. If you do `foo({5, 'A'});`, you might expect to get a string with five A characters (AAAAA) because there's a constructor for that. However, even though 5 isn't a `char`, it is still convertible to one, meaning you actually get the character with the value 5 (likely a control character), followed by a single A. That's how greedy these are. The `(const char*, size_t)` call works because `"abcde"` isn't convertible to `char`.

Comment: Going back to the example from the question, it's more obvious to see why `foo({});` knows to make a `string` from the braces - there's only one type it could be! In the same way, there's a rule saying that the `MyItem foo{{}};` call will create an `initializer_list<double>` from the elements (just the inner `{}` here) if at all possible. There's another rule saying that to make a `double` from `{}`, you get the value 0.0. Put these together and you can see that it is possible to make an `initializer_list<double>` - one element, where `{}` is turned into 0.0.

Comment: Thanks. Just to unstick from 1-element example here is the way to create initializer_list with 3 double `MyItem{{},{},{}}` - so it already knows the type from the template parameter.

Answer (score 5):

This expression

```
MyItem{{}}
```

denotes explicit type conversion (the functional notation).

According to the C++ Standard (5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation))

> 3. Similarly, a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by a
>      braced-init-list creates a temporary object of the specified type
>      direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the specified braced-init-list,
>      and its value is that temporary object as a prvalue.

Class MyItem has conversion initializer-list constructor

```
MyItem(std::initializer_list<double> l) {
    std::cout << "l size " << l.size() << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

that is selected for the explicit type conversion. In fact it is equivalent to the call

```
MyItem( {{}} );
```

So the constructor gets an initializer list with one element

```
{ {} }
```

A scalar object of type double can be initialized with an empty braces `{}`.

As result the expression creates a temporary object of type `MyItem` which is initialized by an initializer list that contains one element of type double that is value-initialized by means of empty braces.